# Scene View quality much better than Game View in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm testing with WaterProDayTime include in Unity Standard Asset and realize that somehow my Scene View look better than Game View, even the refection effect and the refection distort is better. I try to build the game but it look the same at the Game View at highest quality. Can anyone help me please

PS: sorry for my bad English and thanks in advance.

Screenshot of my project:

[image: screenshot of my project]

Comment: It looks like your camera is at a strange angle and the field of view could use some tweaking. Have you tried changing some settings on the camera ?

Comment: Could you post your camera's settings or some results how it looks like now?

Comment: Thank for your help, i change Camera Skybox and the water reflect right.
However, i have played around with the camera setting but the GameView still look suck @@. Here's a screen shot of my camera setting: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_tnxCHePM8U15mPKXOtKWe7RYh7Gle-p/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Here's a screen shot of my camera setting: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_tnxCHePM8U15mPKXOtKWe7RYh7Gle-p/view

Comment: It seem like after i Change camera Projection to Orthographic, the water reflect more accurate, and the graphic quality is much better. Here the results: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NxGTef-QSksotVK3ZtmBAuw7dED3nebW/view?usp=sharing      _PS: i still love to use Camera Perspective in my project. Can you help me improve it :D, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Orthographic projection on your scene view, and your camera view is set to Perspective. So all the calculations of the water's reflection are different. Obviously changing the game to Orthographic view would sacrifice a lot.

The only solution I can think of is use perspective and tweak the settings of the water's surface, in order to make it look as close as possible to the desired result.

Unfortunately, considering how the Math works behind the scenes, the only alternative is to manually change the water's script, which I guess is not the best choice.